# Как вводить команды в Emacs?

Tags: linux, emacs

Недавно начал пользоваться Emacs и встретился с проблемой - табуляция слишком маленькая (2 пробела). Поискав инфу вычитал, что в emacs нужно прописать setq-default tab-width 4, чтобы изменить табуляцию с двух на четыре пробела. Но не понял как и где это нужно писать. Где и как это нужно писать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это вам надо указать в конфигурационном файле, который находится в директории пользователя

> /home/<имя пользователя>/.emacs

файла по умолчанию может не быть. Чтобы выполнять команды в emacs, используйте комбинацию alt + x для вызова командной строки.

Чтобы немного разобраться с emacs, посмотрите [справку](http://emacs.org.ru/emacs/index.html).

Comment: Для установки переменной в текущем сеансе можно использовать буфер \*scratch\* или даже текущий буфер (конечно если он модифицируемый - ввести прямо в тексте (setq variable value)^X^E^Xu)

Answer (score 4):

Каждая команда (например `find-file` или `next-line`) в Emacs является Emacs Lisp функцией. Но помимо команд (которые могут быть или не быть привязаны к клавиатурным комбинациям), есть и много других функций. В Emacs встроен Emacs Lisp интерпретатор, а значит каждую функцию можно выполнить в любой момент. **uvlad** уже показал, как сделать так, чтобы функция выполнялась при каждом запуске Emacs.

Но если нужно выполнить функцию временно — т.е. при перезагрузке Emacs изменение, сделанное функцией, сбросится — то можно нажать <kbd>Alt+Shift+;</kbd>. В минибуфере можно будет ввести `(setq-default tab-width 4)`. Скобки обязательны, потому что это синтаксис Лиспа: `(название-функции аргумент1 аргумент2 ...)`.

Если хочется вызвать полноценный интерпретатор чтобы вводить выполнять разные функции Emacs Lisp, то он называется IELM, и его можно вызвать, если нажать <kbd>Alt+x</kbd> и ввести `ielm`.

Не все функции можно вызвать через <kbd>Alt+x</kbd>, только интерактивные, но т.к. их великое множество, то я рекомендую почитать мануал о вызове интерактивных команд: [Running Commands by Name @ GNU Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/M_002dx.html#M_002dx).

Comment: Я бы добавил -- начать освоение emacs можно со встроенного интерактивного руководства, введя комбинацию из пары символов -- `Ctrl-h Ctrl-t` в любом окошке. Если читать внимательно, то далее все элементарно раскручивается (с помощью встроенной в emacs довольно подробной документации).